# Advice required on career - updated with recent status

Tags: job-change, india

Career details

I have completed B.Tech. 20 years back, and worked in a single Indian software company these 20 years, in mainframes initially, and later, with diminishing requirements in mainframe, got only excel and people management work. Laid off from job recently.

Personality

I am shy and like to be an individual contributor or lead kind of role where I am close to the actual work being done. Not liking pure people management, not good at controlling others.

Next step

I always wanted to continue higher studies, obtaining master's degree, but could not pursue due to high work pressure at job. I have now enrolled for M Tech entrance exam, and studying for it, liking it.

Questions in mind

Not sure if I will be able to compete with younger people. Also, if I pass the exam, complete MTech, specialize in data science, what next? Will I get a job at that age? Am I just wasting my time studying mathematics for the exam, just because I am liking it? Should I have spent more time searching for a new job, and trying to reskill? But it's very frustrating keep applying for jobs and no response ... I am mentally feeling good when studying mathematics for the exam, and imagining getting a good job after 2 years, after a lot of hard work during my masters. Also, if I want to be a mathematics teacher, is it too late? What's the process for changing career to a teacher?
Suggestions from experienced persons, who have probably made a career change, will help me a lot.

Update after 5 months:

Hi all, thanks for your advices in my difficult time. I have recently cleared the master's degree entrance exam for a very prestigious institute in India, and got a rank 2 in the exam (that confirms truth in your advice that age really does not matter). I am feeling excited now, as I don't have to get stuck in mainframe or pure managerial rat race anymore, and I will soon have a chance to learn much interesting new technologies like image processing and artificial intelligence. Hoping I will be able to retain my spirit, after the semesters start with study-pressure.

Comment: Don't let younger people intimidate you. I entered a computer science PhD program in my early 50's, 25 years after finishing my master's degree. I had no problem completing courses intended for people in their 20's with good, recent bachelor's or master's degrees.

Comment: Could you please edit your wall of text to make it more legible? That may be why people downvoted you A few paragraphs and blank lines would help greatly. Good luck in your job search.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my post with recent updates and 'thank you' message for the good advices I had received earlier, but got 2 more downvotes. I wish the reasons for the downvotes were communicated to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, there is a job for everyone in this world. Register that strongly in the mind and everything else will fall in place.

One doesn't compete with youngsters; one competes with oneself. Experience over age is always a plus point. Start focusing on that aspect.

You are doing the right thing during this pandemic; pursuing your interest towards Mathematics. That is no mean feat. A person's learning abilities and perception, ability to solve a problem increases over the time and you have that at your disposal. Pursue what you are good at and always be positive.

In every industry, people need to be controlled. Even students need to be controlled. You might be good at teaching, but if you cannot control or train them properly, you'll be the same position as you are today, frustrated.

There are posts here which are related to pursuing career in teaching profession. Go through those for a better clarity.

There are quite a few things that are mentioned in your post, your software profession, interest to pursue your master's, interest in teaching career.

Make a clear note of what you really want, its pros and cons; this is going to take time. Be patient, everything else will fall in place.

Comment: There is a job fir everyone? Do you mean that literally like "everyone who wants to have a job can be employed"?